# Loop through all cells in GridView and do function on decimals

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, foreach

I'm using a `GridView` with lots of data (both strings and decimals).

I have to loop through all the cells and if a cell is a decimal I have to run a function on that decimal.

Can't find a solution, any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide some of your code? It would be useful to know what the function you are going to run on these cells is and at what point you want to run the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you choose the right DGV.

/!\ BE CAREFUL /!\

Remember **Decimal.TryParse** works with the **CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat**
So make sure you use or set the correct **Culture.**

```
'Check every row
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    'Check every cell
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
        Dim number As Decimal
            'Check if decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString, number) Then
                'Wohoo I am a decimal
            Else
                ' :( I Am not a decimal
            End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I'm going to post this comment on all answers here. This question doesn't quite show any effort from the OP. Really it should be left well alone until the OP provides the necessary information for an accurate answer to be left. By answering questions like this you are saying it's OK to post bad questions.

Comment: @Bugs thanks for the information ill make sure not to answer unstructured questions from now on.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you will need 2 cicles, i don't test the code, but will be someting like that:

```
For i = 0 To GridActive.rows.count - 1
For j = 0 To GridActive.Columns.count - 1
If GridActive.Item(i, j).value.contains(",") Then
Call DecimalFunction()
End If
Next
Next
```

Comment: I though of that first but then I went for the **Decimal.TryParse** because maybe in his culture its the "," and not "."

Comment: You're right, with **Decimal.TryParse** you have the slightest risk of error that the **contains** might bring

Comment: I'm going to post this comment on all answers here. This question doesn't quite show any effort from the OP. Really it should be left well alone until the OP provides the necessary information for an accurate answer to be left. By answering questions like this you are saying it's OK to post bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you require to call your function at the time of gridview bind then you have to do the code in rowdatabound event as follows: (This is pseudo code.)

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

  For Each TableCell  As DataGridViewCell In row.Cell
       If Decimal Condition = Yes Then ' Put your condition

        Else

        End If
  Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to post this comment on all answers here. This question doesn't quite show any effort from the OP. Really it should be left well alone until the OP provides the necessary information for an accurate answer to be left. By answering questions like this you are saying it's OK to post bad questions.

Comment: Make sense. Will make sure moving forward. Thanks to notify buddy.